# Array Search in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I am Trying search an array to find another smaller array Values. I used a nested loop and values found are displayed perfectly. but, I want also to print the values not found, can anyone help me improving my code so that value not found be printed in the loop, without using literal as I did in my code (code block // improving code)

Hope anyone can Help.

```
( class Program  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intArray = { 5, 12, 0, 67, 75, 3, 27, 1, 98};
        int[] searchValues = { 0, 25, 99, 12, 3 };
        for (int i = 0; i < searchValues.Length; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j< intArray.Length; ++j)
            { 
                if (searchValues[i]== intArray[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} Has been found in index {1} of intarray ", searchValues[i], j);
                }               
            }
            // improve the code
            if (i == 1 || i == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} was Not found in intarray ", searchValues[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make code much readable If you swap nested loops on [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) and [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) functions. Code would look like:

```
int[] intArray = { 5, 12, 0, 67, 75, 3, 27, 1, 98 };
int[] searchValues = { 0, 25, 99, 12, 3 };


foreach (var arr in searchValues)
{
     int index = Array.IndexOf(intArray, arr);
     if (index != -1)
           Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} Has been found in index {1} of intarray ", arr, index);
     else
           Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} was Not found in intarray ", arr);
 }

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( class Program  
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intArray = { 5, 12, 0, 67, 75, 3, 27, 1, 98};
        int[] searchValues = { 0, 25, 99, 12, 3 };

        foreach (int item in searchValues)
           if (Array.IndexOf(intArray, item)!= -1)
               Console.Writeline("Item exists in list: ",item)
           else Console.Writeline("Item does not exist in list: ",item)

        Console.Read();
    }
})
```

Comment: The code can be re-writen if you are interested in the index also (but you mentioned only the value)

Comment: intArray.FindIndex(s => s.Contains(item)) //(to get the index)

Comment: You're already using `IndexOf`, no need to also bring in `FindIndex`.

Comment: now he can save the index of found element in a variable if he needs it afterwards (instead of only checking if it is -1)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to store the index in a variable, then check its value after the conclusion of the inner `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < searchValues.Length; ++i)
{
    int idx = -1;

    for (int j = 0; j< intArray.Length; ++j)
    { 
        if (searchValues[i] == intArray[j])
        {
            idx = j;
            break;
        }               
    }
    // improve the code
    if (idx >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} Has been found in index {1} of intarray ", searchValues[i], idx);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} was Not found in intarray ", searchValues[i]);
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to use LINQ:

```
int[] intArray = { 5, 12, 0, 67, 75, 3, 27, 1, 98};
int[] searchValues = { 0, 25, 99, 12, 3 };

var indices = searchValues.Select(i => new { Value = i, Index = Array.IndexOf(intArray, i) });
var foundValues = indices.Where(x => x.Index >= 0).ToArray();
var unfoundValues = indices.Where(x => x.Index < 0).ToArray();

foreach (var val in foundValues)
    Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} Has been found in index {1} of intarray ", val.Value, val.Index);

foreach (var val in unfoundValues)
    Console.WriteLine("The Value {0} was Not found in intarray ", val.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**A shorter solution with LINQ:**

```
searchValues.ToList().Where(val => intArray.Contains(val)).ToList().ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index of {0}:\t {1}", val, Array.IndexOf(intArray, val))));
searchValues.ToList().Where(val => !intArray.Contains(val)).ToList().ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index of {0}:\t {1}", val, "None")));
```

Output for:

```
int[] intArray = { 5, 12, 0, 67, 75, 3, 27, 1, 98 };
int[] searchValues = { 0, 25, 99, 12, 3 };
```

*Index of 0:      2*

*Index of 12:     1*

*Index of 3:      5*

*Index of 25:     None*

*Index of 99:     None*

Or if you don't mind the print sequence:

```
searchValues.ToList().Select(val => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(val, Array.IndexOf(intArray, val))).ToList().ForEach(kvp => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index of {0}:\t {1}", kvp.Key, (kvp.Value == -1 ? "None" : kvp.Value.ToString()))));
```

*Index of 0:      2*

*Index of 25:     None*

*Index of 99:     None*

*Index of 12:     1*

*Index of 3:      5*

Answer (score -1):

Make another temporary array same as search array having same values and instead matching with search array match with temporary array then when your if statement becomes true and you display the value that matched update that value of your  temporary array with `int_max` . after all work display the values of your temporary array that are not equal to `int_max`. Now the values that are not matched will be displayed. This is simplest one.

Comment: Can you please add some source-code to backup your theory?